# How to display selection filter outside table column for material-table reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) to display table data. and Add filters for a particular column outside the table.

Example: 
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/filtering

I want to filter only "birth place" data using selection dropdown  outside the table separately and not inside the column head

Answer (score 0):

I think material table contains only basic functionality, so what you ask is not available out of box.

Simplest solution is to wrap table inside other component which will contain table and 'birth place' select in jsx, **birthPlace** and **filteredTableData** in state and tableData as class property.

Initially

> filteredTableData = tableData

and it proxied to table component. And inside **birthPlaceSelect** **onChange** event you should implement filtering **tableData** and set it in state as **filteredTableData**.

So basically you filtering data outside table by yourself.

```
class FilterableTable extends Component {
  state = {
    filteredTableData: [],
    birthPlace: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // load data or get it from store in loadDataFromServer
    loadDataFromServer().then(data => {
      // save initial data to state
      this.setState({ filteredTableData: data });
      // and save copy to class prop
      this.data = data;
    });
  }

  onFilterValueChanged = ev => {
    if (ev.target.value) {
      this.setState({
        filteredTableData: this.data.filter(row =>
          row.birthPlace.contains(ev.target.value)
        ),
      });
    }else{
      this.setState({
        filteredTableData: this.data        
      });
    }
  };


  render() {
    const { filteredTableData, birthPlace } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input value={birthPlace} onChange={this.onFilterValueChanged} />
        <MaterialTable data={filteredTableData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```